# Dispose winforms usercontrol with picturebox - currently leaking memory

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, user-controls

Firstly, I've read multiple questions and answers *similar* but not the same as the issue I'm having - I believe this is not a duplicate.

In short, my application is leaking memory.

I have a `Flowpanel` containing multiple instances of a UserControl which in tern contains two `Picturebox` controls and a `Label` and a `ToolTip`.

My Usercontrol is immutable and each instance contains some status information and a couple of images which are from `Properties.Resources` object.

When the status is changed I remove the usercontrol from the flowpanel and replace it with a new one. This is causing the memory usage to constantly increase for my application.

**I suspect I'm not correctly disposing the usercontrol or picturebox somehow - but not sure where?**

**UserControl:**

```
public partial class ucArrayStatus : UserControl
{
    private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    public ucArrayStatus(string arrayDesc, ArrayStatus status /*this is an enum*/)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labArrayDesc.Text = arrayDesc;
        labStatus.Text = status.ToString();
        toolTip.SetToolTip(this, status.ToString());
        if (status == ArrayStatus.Complete)
        {
            //pbStatusIcon is a PictureBox control
            pbStatusIcon.Image = Properties.Resources.complete;
            pbStatusIcon.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }
        else
        {
            pbStatusIcon.Image = Properties.Resources.working;
            pbStatusIcon.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        }
    }
}
```

**Do I need to add a Dispose() to this class to explicitly dispose the Image ?**

**Creation and removal of usercontrols:**

```
public class ArrayUIHandler
{
    //store each usercontrol in a specific order indexed by this dictionary
    private Dictionary<int, ucArrayStatus> configToControl = new Dictionary<int, ucArrayStatus>();
    private void ApplyStatusItem(int index, ArrayStatus status)
    {
        var item = new ucArrayStatus(CreateArrayStatusDescription(), status);
        container.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            lock (accessLock)
            {
                if (!configToControl.ContainsKey(index))
                {
                    Logger.Log("UpdateStatus(): Unable to find array: {0}. ControlCount: {1}", index, 
                                container.Controls.Count);
                }
                var c = configToControl[index]; //extract from dictionary
                var controlIndex = container.Controls.IndexOf(c); //retrieve from flowpanel           

                container.Controls.Remove(c); //remove from flowpanel controlcollection
                configToControl.Remove(index); //remove from dictionary
//dispose (not sure if more is needed here, or to implement dispose in the usercontrol??)
                c.Dispose();
                c = null; //explicitly set to null - not sure if needed?
                container.Controls.Add(item); //add new usercontrol to flowpanel
                container.Controls.SetChildIndex(item, controlIndex); //set index position
                configToControl.Add(index, item); //add to dictionary

            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Most posts I've seen have issues due to loading the image from a file or byte array etc, does this apply when using the `Resources` object as I am here?

**Edit1**

Adding a `Dispose()` method to the usercontrol doesn't seem to have resolved the problem.

Code:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (pbStatusIcon.Image != null))
    {
        pbStatusIcon.Image.Dispose();
        pbStatusIcon.Image = null;
        pbStatusIcon.Dispose();

    }
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: _does this apply when using the Resources object_ Yes, you load the resource bitmap into a new bitmap and will have to dispose of that, when done with it. Also, disposing just of the containing UC is not enough. All Bitmaps you have added must be disposed of!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar enough to yours, I messed around with a few things and found this to work.

Dispose of the image(I had mine setup as variables)

pictureBox1Image.Dispose();

pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = null;

I would suggest trying that first and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm currently running a test using this method, annoyingly the app needs to run on a remote server so I'm unable to use the visual studio memory debugging functionality

Answer (score 0):

Check all the Disposable objects you have and call Dispose for all of them. I can see you have a **Tooltip which is Disposable**. Make sure you dispose all disposable instance. That's the general best practice rule.